# Progressive loading codesnip not quite understood

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working on making an element progressive load so make the loading of hero banners more fluent,  I came by this code example:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aPdJKv)

The one I can't seem to understand is how the placeholder image is being switched to the original image.

The javascript does not seem to refer to original image at all?
So how does it render it?

I am currently getting a white screen when I use the javascript, which makes sense as the blurred image becomes more opacity =1 =>

```
$(function(){

  $('.progressive-image').each(function(){

    var image = new Image();
    var previewImage = $(this).find('.loadingImage');
    var newImage = $(this).find('.overlay');

    image.onload = function(){
      newImage.css('background-image', 'url(' + image.src + ')');
      newImage.css('opacity', '1');
      console.log('complete');
    };

    image.src = previewImage.data('image');

  });

});
```

So how does this codepen blen the original image in and the blurred image out?
the  tag which `newimage` finds does not contain the image? so even more confusion?

Comment: Were you able to get it figured out?

Comment: yes, I am not sure whether the approach genius, or there is better way to do it? but I will go with it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little confusing but the code doesn't actually remove the old image. It inserts a new image into `<div class="overlay"></div>`, which overlays the 'loading' image in `<div class="loadingImage"></div>`.

Look at your `Elements` tab in inspector and you'll be able to see both of these.

**How does this work?**

More specifically the script grabs the 'full res' image url from the `data-image` tag in the `loading-image` div.

```
<div 
  class="loadingImage"
  style="background: url('https://res.cloudinary.com/sourcetoad/image/upload/v1483582294/frog-2-sm_zjphps.jpg')"
  data-image="https://res.cloudinary.com/sourcetoad/image/upload/v1483582295/frog-2-lg_vahxhg.jpg">
</div>
```

It grabs the `data-image` with:

```
image.src = previewImage.data('image');
```

Then it inserts it as a background image into the `overlay` div with:

```
newImage.css('background-image', 'url(' + image.src + ')');
```

Comment: I am approving your answer as it seem to answer my prior question, could you perhaps elaborate on how `data-image` is being extracted using preview.data('image') I only seem to be able the image using 
`previewImage.context.dataset["image"];`

Comment: `data()` is a jQuery method. You can read more about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/misc_data.asp

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of a funky example to look at, I got a bit lost in it as well.

`newImage.css('background-image', 'url(' + image.src + ')');`

This line of code sets the image on the `<div class="overlay"></div>`

Overlay is actually the real image, not the blurred image.

The Blurred Image is set with an inline style on `<div class="loadingImage>`

I have to admit I'm not a huge fan of what this codepen is doing, but that's how it is working.

One tip for picking something like this apart, start commenting out javascript lines to see how it works before the JS takes over.

I hope this helps.